# git "expected shallow list" error when shallow had tested as true

Tags: travis-ci

I have a repo that, when tested on Travis, consistently gives an error like:

```
$ if [[ -a .git/shallow ]]; then git fetch --unshallow; fi
fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list
The command "if [[ -a .git/shallow ]]; then git fetch --unshallow; fi" failed and exited with 128 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

You can see [an example here](https://travis-ci.org/JuliaGraphics/Immerse.jl/builds/83426931), although it's possible that link requires authorization.

What I find strange about this that it seems the `git fetch --unshallow` should run only if it's already determined that it is shallow. I should add that I've used this construct in many other repositories and never had a problem.

On my local machine, the contents of `.git` are:

```
myrepo.git$ ls -a
.   branches        config       FETCH_HEAD  HEAD   index  logs     ORIG_HEAD                                                        
..  COMMIT_EDITMSG  description  gitk.cache  hooks  info   objects  refs
```

Comment: I'm also having this issue, but only on one of four builds. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

I am not hip to the internals of Git, nor do I really understand what `git fetch --unshallow` is actually supposed to do, but one possibility: check which version of `git` you have available to your Travis test runners.

I see the same `fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list` error message with a GitLab CI/CD shell runner on CentOS 7 VMs. CentOS 7 only has Git 1.8.something in the official repos.

[This blog post](https://megamorf.gitlab.io/2020/03/19/fix-gitlab-runner-expected-shallow-list-error/) is where I initially became aware of this error message being related to an old version of Git. That post suggests upgrading the OS-default version of `git` with third-party repos, which I didn't want to do.

What I ended up doing instead, as advised [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/60466#note_202961108), was setting:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
```

in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. This is, of course, a GitLab-specific thing, but I'm pretty positive Travis gives you some option for setting environment variables for your test environment.

---

See also:

1. [gitlab runner doesn`t work on a specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663096/gitlab-runner-doesnt-work-on-a-specific-project/59472034#59472034) (Ryan Daniels' answer)