# gitlab runner should use specific git binary

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

## Short story

How to tell `gitlab-runner` to use this specific git installation, e.g. at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git`?

## Context

I am using a `gitlab-runner` with `shell` executor to build docker images.
However the pipeline already fails at the beginning with

> fatal: git fetch-pack: expected shallow list
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

This is clearly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663096/gitlab-runner-doesnt-work-on-a-specific-project). There are also good solution metioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59472034/7403431).

One of them is to install a newer version of `git`.
The current `git --version` gives `git version 1.8.3.1` which is the system default.
On the same machine I have GitLab running which comes with a newer version of `git`.

Via  `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info` I find that a newer git (`/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git`) is already installed, `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git --version` gives `git version 2.32.0`.

## Attempts

I already tried adding

```
environment = ["PATH=/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin:$PATH"]
```

to the specific `[[runner]]` in my `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` but this seems to overwrite `PATH` completely (the pipeline fails with some mkdir not found error).

Comment: You miss at least a `$` at `:PATH`. Here, you totally wreck the path variable with a constant 'PATH' string.

Comment: @amanin Well spotted, I already corrected the typo. I still have the same issue with the correct `:$PATH`.